# Windows store app ItemsControl HTML-table-like behavior

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make a control to display custom list of checkboxes, like at the image:

[image]

My current implementation uses **ItemsControl** that has **VariableSizedWrapGrid** as an **ItemsPanelTemplate**. But it makes all items same sized... I can't figure out how to make cells sized by content just like in HTML table.

Comment: since he tried VariableSizedWrapGrid  I guess, that he don't want to have uniform grid, but each column adapted to the widest element in that column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, there isn't such panel available by default.

If number of your items is static (or at least number of columns is static), you can use `Grid` as ItemsPanelTemplate, and set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` in `ItemContainerStyle` trough converter.

Otherwise, you need to implement your custom panel by overriding ArrangeChildren and MeasureOverride methods. I have my custom panel that solves this issue. I can share it with you, if you won't find anything better

**EDIT:** I assume that you don't want to have all cells the same size. In that case you could use UniformGrid.

I have attached sample code using Grid + some codebehind. the codebehind is not violation of MVVM separation of concern, because there's pure view logic in codebehind.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid Initialized="ItemsPanel_Initialized" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="Item_Loaded" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>


private void ItemsPanel_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //generate row and column definitions
    for (int i = 0; i < ViewModel.ColumnsCount; i++)
    {
        ((Grid)sender).ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition{ Width = new GridLength()});
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= ViewModel.ItemsSource.Count / ViewModel.ColumnsCount; i++)
    {
        ((Grid)sender).RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition{ Height = new GridLength() });
    }

}

private void Item_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemContainer = (FrameworkElement) sender;
    var itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(itemContainer);
    var itemIndex = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(itemContainer);
    Grid.SetColumn(itemContainer, itemIndex % ViewModel.ColumnsCount);
    Grid.SetRow(itemContainer, itemIndex / ViewModel.ColumnsCount);
}
```

Comment: Please share your panel code. Already several days I'm looking for easy solution and it seems really unexist. UniformGrid isn't available for store app and also seems not to do desired layout.

Comment: Columns number isn't fixed, but is accessible as control's ViewModel property. This is base control to list different entities, not only monthes.

Comment: in that case I recommend you to use Grid. It's much easier and performance is also much better.

Comment: It seems that several workarounds have to be implemented for using Grid, like described here: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html Am I right?

Comment: @iZverev: yep, it is the same principle as I've used. The attached property behaviour is even better than my ItemsPanel_Initialized event handler. I just wanted to keep the example simplistic, but normally I would use attached property, since it is reusable and can be moved to styles and supports databinding

Comment: Had no chance to check, will try today. Thank you!

Comment: I was need to change some logic because of windows store app difference and also add DependencyProperties and bindings because I can't directly reference my VM. But your code helped a lot, thank you very much!